# ASP.NET Web API in asp net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Does any one know is is possible to use ASP.NET Web API in ASP .NET not in Asp MVC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Web API can be used with ASP.NET Web Forms:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We can use Web API in asp.net web forms.

Web API using HTTP protocol to communicate the Clinet.

We can access an web API service using a HTTP request, it supports the GET,POST AND PUT HTTP methods.